# trigger.io: tabs.openWithOptions causes application to crash in Android

Tags: ajax, trigger.io, forge

we are using tabs in calling some authentication for our mobile Application. It seems working before but now, after the toolkit updated, it is now causing to crash our application.

You can see my code if it is the problem:

```
  $(".share_now").live('click' , function(){
  authorize_twitter();
  })

   function authorize_twitter(){
      var url_encode="http://server.com/twitteroauth/login.php";
      forge.tabs.openWithOptions({
      tint:[217, 0, 0, 87],
      url: url_encode,
      pattern: "http://server.com/twitteroauth/complete/*",
      title: 'Login with Twitter'
   }, 
   function (data) {
    forge.logging.log(data);    
   });
   }
```

This is the error of the crash:

[Error Crash Android 2.2 http://content.screencast.com/users/junnel1001/folders/Jing/media/27304ddc-7094-4006-b457-f9de09398026/sample.png](http://content.screencast.com/users/junnel1001/folders/Jing/media/27304ddc-7094-4006-b457-f9de09398026/sample.png)

I hope someone from trigger.io can help this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Same here running on Forge API v1.4.39. The stack trace starts with `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.webkit.WebView.removeJavascriptInterface
    at io.trigger.forge.android.modules.tabs.ModalView$2$3.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(ModalView.java:310)`

Comment: Excellent new features with the latest release guys!  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My apologies - this was caused by a fix that went in while ago getting lost in a merge into v1.4.37: I've pushed v1.4.40 which addresses that!